# Xamarin - Deployment on laptop without hardware acceleration support

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using `MSVS2015Pro` with `C#/Xamarin`.

I have a laptop that doesn't support `Hardware Acceleration`.

Then I have a **question**: can I develop for mobiles without having to spend too much time when deploying?.

I could deploy to my real android phone, but I don't know if that's slower than deploying to an `AVD`. Is it?

What Can I do? I don't wanna do things in a very slow manner.

Do I have to buy a another laptop that supports `Hardware Acceleration`?

If that's the case, what other requirements I need for that other laptop?

Answer (score 1):

We are running windows 10 with VS 2015 Pro and no hardware acceleration available on the CPU. There is indeed a solid state drive and 16gig ram (The ram doesn’t really assist in running the emulator though. More ram doesn't make the emulator faster. It is rather the processor and or GPU. The ram does assist with running multiple emulator instances.)

Doing both xamarin.iOS and xamarin.android development. I would agree that with hardware acceleration things would be much faster but it is possible to dev on an enterprise level without it. The deployment to emulator (once emulator has started up and is running) vs actual device is much the same. It is indeed faster running the app on an actual device. 
I would suggest using actual device to test functionality and the user experience of the app for quick feedback cycles while using the emulator to test different OS versions for compatibility.